# How do I maintain scope when delegating to service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I've built a small service to handle errorMessages in my application. Its publicly available on the rootScope and is able to add new messages to my page as needed. Now the need to have clickable links in the messages have arisen.

Questions:

1. How do I dynamically add JavaScript that is handled by angular to the messages that are created?
   I've added onclicks that work, but ng-click seem to not be handled.
2. The Js that I would like to run is in the controller that created the message in the first place. How do I make sure that I end up in the correct scope when clicking a link in an error message?
3. If the function adding a message is another service, how do I solve that?

And the service I'm playing around with:
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
function errorHandlingFactory() {

    this.messages = [];

    this.addMessage = function (messageText, type) {
        var message = this.messages.push({messageText: messageText, type: type, closeable: false});
    };

    this.getHtmlContent = function(messageId) {
        return this.messages[messageId].messageText;
    }

    this.removeMessage = function (messageId) {
        this.messages.splice(messageId, 1);
    };

    this.clearMessages = function() {
        this.messages = [];
    };
}

myApp.service('errorHandling', function () {
    return new errorHandlingFactory();
});

myApp.run(function($rootScope, errorHandling) {
    // Attach global error handling object to our rootScope
    $rootScope.errorFactory = errorHandling;
});


// Usage from controller
$rootScope.errorFactory.addMessage('The message to be added', 'warning');
```

To make it a bit easier to understand, I've created a jsfiddle to look at.
http://jsfiddle.net/kxsmL25h/7/

What I would like to do is when the link in message is clicked, the function desiredCallback is run on the GenericTestController.

Comment: generally you should avoid updating html from controllers/services and instead use ng-directives or custom directives.  check out angular.element https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: That is very true! Maybe I could use a template for the custom message with links in it to avoid that problem? Will try it out and see if I can make it work.